# How to compare objects in a Node List?

Tags: java, nodes

I am trying to write a method that accepts an Object and compares it to a Node list. And then it adds every element of that list that is smaller than it to a new list. I am pretty close but two of the first elements aren't copying over.

```
public LList<String> getAllLessThan(Comparable<T> anObject) {
    LList<String> newList = new LList();
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (currentNode.data.compareTo((T) anObject) == -1)
        {
            newList.add((String) currentNode.data);
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

The first two elements of the list should be included but are being left out.

```
    String[] names = {"Abby", "Bobby", "Carla", "Doug"};
    LList<String> nameList = new LList(names, 4);

    String[] newNames = {"Edgar", "Frank"};
    nameList.addAll(newNames);
    System.out.println("Output should be Abby, Bobby, Carla, Doug, Edgar, Frank");
    nameList.display();
    System.out.println();

    nameList.add("Carrie");
    LList<String> newList = nameList.getAllLessThan("Doug");
    System.out.println("Output should be Abby, Bobby, Carla, Carrie");
    newList.display();
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: You didn't post the full implementation of `LList` so it's difficult to guess, but if I had to put my money somewhere I would bet that either `length` is not maintained properly or `display()` is buggy.

Comment: what is the value of "length" that you used in the for loop?

Comment: Does LList stand for LinkedList, are you referring to LinkedList<String>?

Answer (score 1):

String.compareTo()

> If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:

```
this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
```

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:

```
this.length()-anotherString.length()
```

The String1.compareTo(String2) method returns:

```
0 when strings are equal
> 0 when String1 > String2
< 0 when String1 < String2
```

Change

```
if (currentNode.data.compareTo((T) anObject) == -1)
```

To

```
if (currentNode.data.compareTo((T) anObject) < 0)
```